# Android webview cant to load daily motion website fully

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to build a apps which will be able to youtube and dailymotion ...
youtube is ok but dailymotion is not load fully,it load's only menu bar with click restricted(no touch allowed)...
How will  i solve it,any idea please...
My sample code for loading `WebView` is here

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new myWebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.dailymotion.com");
```

output window:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten a solution that can solve this problem..i have given my code here if would be beneficial..

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new myWebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); 
  webView.loadUrl("http://www.dailymotion.com");
```